# VSTFS build error - SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I am new to CI. I have a build defined. I am getting the following error when i queue the build:

```
2018-10-08T09:54:50.0136696Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.https://testurl.extraheader
2018-10-08T09:54:50.1425808Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.proxy
2018-10-08T09:54:50.2763750Z ##[command]git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ********" fetch --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
2018-10-08T09:54:51.1465256Z fatal: unable to access 'https://testdomain/tfs/Project/_git/Project.Test/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
2018-10-08T09:54:51.1719172Z ##[error]Git fetch failed with exit code: 128
```

Comment: Which version of agent do you use?

Answer (score 7):

This error occurs when a self-signed certificate cannot be verified.

Here is the same issue discussed on GitHub : https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/688

You can try below workarounds:

- Add Enterprise CA certificate to `git config –global http.sslCAInfo`.
- Tell Git where to find the CA bundle by running:

  `git config --system http.sslCAPath /absolute/path/to/git/certificates`
- Modify the `ca-bundle.crt` file to include the domain's root cert
  which found in the `<agent install directory>\externals\git\mingw64\ssl\certs` folder.
- Turn off sslVerify with:

  `git config --system http."https://our.internal:port/".sslVerify false`
- Try following the tutorial which mentioned in below blog:
  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phkelley/2014/01/20/adding-a-corporate-or-self-signed-certificate-authority-to-git-exes-store/
- Try to [deploy an new agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts) using the [release 2.129.0 agent](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/releases/tag/v2.129.0) which
  contains git SChannel support.

  To enable git to use `SChannel`, you need to pass `--gituseschannel`
  during agent config. ex:

  `./config.cmd --gituseschannel`

You can also reference the solutions mentioned in this thread: [SSL certificate problem: Unable to get local issuer certificate](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-816521128.html)